# Show a tag in parentheses when connecting through SSH

Tags: command-line, ssh

This is probably a pretty silly question, but one that I can't find the answer anywhere because of the description of the problem:

I have 2 linux servers. One is TEST and another is PROD

when I connect through SSH to them, this is what's shown:

```
(TEST) ubuntu@ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX:
```

and

```
(PROD) ubuntu@ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX:
```

How do you configure each server to show that tag? And how to manage it if I want to replace/remove?

EDIT:
I've found out why but not sure how.
The servers are hosted in AWS, so it's some custom Linux image they are using.
The server is forwarding a parameter called "environment" in AWS tags into the bashrc but I can't find where is doing that

Comment: It's changing the `PS1` variable, probably somewhere in to the `.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` files. Check those files in those servers.

Comment: The `PS1` variable can be used to both set the prompt, but also the title of the window in Xterm (between the codes `\e]0;` and `\a`). Also [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456228/bash-ps1-window-title).